# shell script $$ value

Tags: shell, scripting

When I use these shell commands:

```bsh
[root@linux /tmp]# a=$$
[root@linux /tmp]# echo $a
3985
```

where does the value 3985 come from? And why?

Comment: Notice that using $$ for generating temp file names have poor security implications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
man bash
```

explains it.

```
Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, 
it expands to the  process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.
```

Answer (score 3):

$$ is the pid of the current process

try

```
host@controller:~$ echo $$
12481
host@controller:~$ ps -p 12481
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
12481 pts/2    00:00:01 bash
host@controller:~$
```

Since we execute `echo $$` in bash, we get it's current pid

know also

echo $? is the return code of the last executed command.

$# is the number of arguments

$* is the list of arguments passed to the current process

$[1 or 2 or ... n] value of each corresponding argument

Answer (score 0):

That's why some people use it to construct a filename that's only used temporarily and then destroyed, as in this script fragment.

```
SCRATCHFILE=/tmp/emphemeral.$$ ;
# Now have the script write to and read from the temp file
rm $SCRATCHFILE ;
```

As mentioned above, the $$ in the filename will be the PID of the main script.

Comment: You should use `mktemp` for this.

Answer (score -1):

Try "echo $$" you will get the answer.